# How can I use query syntax from Linq for return random records?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq

How can I use query syntax from Linq for return random records?

Something like the following tsql statement:

```
select top 10 * from sometable ORDER BY NewID()
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be equivalent:

```
var query =
    (from s in sometable      
    orderby Guid.NewGuid()    //Ordering by Guid.NewGuid() is the same as newid()
    select s)
    .Take(10);                //This cannot be done in query syntax.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Guid.NewGuid()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx) with linq

```
var results = db.sometable.OrderBy(r => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(10);
```

or in query syntax:

```
var results = (from s in sometable orderby Guid.NewGuid() select s).Take(10);
```